# What is the relationship between Stash and Bitbucket?

Tags: repository, bitbucket

- Are Bitbucket and Stash the same application?
- As far as I understand Bitbucket was called before Stash?
- How the moving from one system to the other is done?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the Stash was just renamed to Bitbucket. 
I performed the migration from Stash to Bitbucket for one of our clients around a year ago. If my memory serves me right, the process was relatively painless. I first exported the data from Stash using the native export functionality, then I did a [fresh Bitbucket install](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/install-or-upgrade-bitbucket-server-859468469.html) and afterwards just imported the Stash data in the freshly set up instance. 
Your mileage may warry though depending on how big the repositories are and from what version are you migrating from. But I'm sure somebody at [Atlassian Community forums](https://community.atlassian.com/) will be able to help you out if you run into any issues. Or if you have SEN, just write to [Atlassian support](https://support.atlassian.com/).